# Is it possible to set timeout for incorrect login attempt for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database-administration

I'm using `cloud.mongodb.com` replica set. From security perspective, I see only white list of IP addresses.

I would like to set some timeout on mongo side after some amount of unsuccessful login attempts from same IP address. Is it possible?

Comment: You're gonna have to write your own logic for that, I'm assuming right now you're trying to match a password and username thus an unsuccessful match is just finding nothing - you cant trigger "nothing" without writing your own logic.

Comment: I mean that I want to do it on **Mongo** side, not in my application.

Comment: I understand, the example I gave was suppose to show that it's not possible